# Android - use variable from another class

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to use two variable from  `aff.java` in `MainActivity.java` to take GPS coordinate from SMS. i tried with Gson and i added two other classes `profil.java` and `profilstatic.java` but my application didn t work. Please help me.

MainAvtivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        double lat1,lon1;    
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              TextView view = new TextView(this);
              Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
              Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
              String sms = "";
              while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                  String spn ="+21626938812";
                  String phNum =cur.getString(2);
                  if (spn.equals(phNum)){
                  sms +=cur.getString(12); 
                                  }      
                  }

                 String a =sms.substring(0,10);
                 String b =sms.substring(11,21); 
                 double lat = Double.parseDouble(a);
                 double lon = Double.parseDouble(b);



                lat1=lat;
                lon1=lon;
                Profil profil = new Gson().fromJson("", Profil.class); 
                profil.setLat(lat1);
                profil.setLon(lon1);
                ProfilStatique.setProfil(profil);
                Intent activity_main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aff.class) ;

                startActivity(activity_main);

          }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

aff.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class aff extends MapActivity {
    double lat1,lon1;

    Profil profil = ProfilStatique.getProfil();
    MapView maMap;
    MapController monControler;


    double latitude = profil.getLat() ;
    double longitude = profil.getLon() ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        maMap = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.myGmap);
        maMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint (microdegrees(latitude),microdegrees(longitude));

        MonOverlay object = new MonOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_voisinage_rouge));
        object.addPoint(point);
        maMap.getOverlays().add(object);
        maMap.setSatellite(true);

        monControler = maMap.getController();
        monControler.setZoom(12);
        monControler.setCenter(point);

    }


    private int microdegrees (double value){
        return (int)(value*1000000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    public class MonOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{

        List<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

        public MonOverlay(Drawable arg0) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(arg0));
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            GeoPoint point = points.get(i);
            return new OverlayItem(point,"titre","description");
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {

            return points.size();
        }

        public void addPoint (GeoPoint point){
            this.points.add(point);
            populate();
        }

    }

}
```

Profil.java

```
public class Profil {



  public double lat,lon;

public double getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public double getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(double lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}

}
```

ProfilStatic.java

```
public class ProfilStatique {

    private static Profil profil = new Profil();

    public static Profil getProfil() {
        return profil;
    }
    public static void setProfil(Profil profil) {
        ProfilStatique.profil = profil;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wanting to pass data back to the calling activity, then you should be using `startActivityForResult()` in `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: i want to pass data to aff.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing data from one activity to another, it should be done through the intent, via the Bundle. From the Activity that is passing the values, you'd do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, RecievingActivity.class);
i.putExtra("lat", lat1);
i.putExtra("long", lon1);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, in the recieving activity's onCreate method, you'd do something like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
lat1 = bundle.getLong("lat");
lon1 = bundle.getLong("long");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create another class called Store.java and create two public static variables. In that way you will have those variables globally accessible. You can then change or access values in those two variables from anywhere within the application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am sorry, i didn t understand you, how can i take my variable lat and lon in Store.java? and when i add this classe, should i delete profil.java and profilstatic.java ?